# Laravel profile image in navbar

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have `userprofile` table which has relationship with `user` table, in `userprofile` table I have `userImg` where I store image name, When I load the image from home page, it workes properly, such as:

```
<img src="../storage/profil/{{Auth::user()->userprofile->userImg}}">
```

But when I go to a page where the storage/profil is 3 dots or 1 dot away than It doesn't work properly, what is the best way to load the image into navbar?

Note that my navbar is in a file called `includes` and I included it in `master` layer

Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `url()`-

```
<img src="{{url('storage/profil/'.Auth::user()->userprofile->userImg)}}" alt="...">
```

Comment: Perfect, I learn a ton of stuff everyday, Can I assume when I give url like that It laravel ends up in public folder and proceeds from there?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create the symbolic link from your `public/storage` directory to your `storage/app/public` directory so you can access the files.  You can do that with:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

And access them as an asset with:

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/profil/Auth::user()->userprofile->userImg')}}">
```

Check out the [documentation on the public disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: Ahhh yeah I linked it already, I'm accesing it from one page but not every page. But I assume asset thing would be another way to go. Thanks for the answer